# MAX In WHERE clause return all the record

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to return the `MAX` gameweek of the available `match` of a specific `round`, for doing this I used the `MAX` function, but I got all the `matches` gameweeks of a round, instead I should get only the `matches` which have the `MAX` gameweek.

This is my query:

```
  SELECT m.id, m.round_id, m.gameweek
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN competition_rounds r ON m.round_id = r.id
  LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON r.season_id = s.id
  LEFT JOIN competition c ON c.id = s.competition_id
  WHERE 1 AND m.status = 5 AND m.round_id = 488 OR m.round_id = 489 OR m.round_id = 490 OR m.round_id = 491 
  AND m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(gameweek) FROM `match` WHERE (round_id = 488) OR (round_id = 489) OR (round_id = 490) OR (round_id = 491))
```

the result is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1979011",
         "round_id": "488",
         "gameweek": "1",
    },
    {
        "id": "1979012",
        "round_id": "488",
        "gameweek": "2",
    },
    {
        "id": "1979013",
        "round_id": "489",
        "gameweek": "1",
    },
    {
        "id": "1979014",
        "round_id": "489",
        "gameweek": "2",
    },
```

I'm expecting instead only the match which have as id: 1979012, 1979014. Why I get all the matches gameweeks?

Comment: `x AND y OR z` is the same as `( x AND y ) OR z`, not `x AND ( y OR z )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need parentheses.  Or better yet, use `in`:

```
WHERE 1 AND
      m.status = 5 AND
      m.round_id IN (488, 489, 490, 491) AND
      m.gameweek = (SELECT MAX(m2.gameweek)
                    FROM `match` m2
                    WHERE m2.round_id IN (488, 489, 490, 491)
                   )
```

It is entirely unclear to me why you are joining so many tables together.  You are only referencing columns from `match`, so that would seem to be the only table needed in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the question I semplified the query, the full query looks like this: https://pastebin.com/RMKP29Pd the join are made for take the details from other table, anyway, I used your solution but I get the exact result, maybe you can see something that I can't? Thank again

Comment: okay my bad, I added the `m.round_id IN (488, 489, 490, 491)` and now seems to work, but I've another problem now, the matches returned correspond only to 488 round id, the other round missing..

Comment: @Gordon, Can you explain `WHERE 1 AND`? Coz I don't think it is needed here.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . The `1 AND` is in the original query.

Comment: Exactly what was my question. Why we need to Use `AND 1` here. 1 means true. If we only use rest conditions that will also work for us. 1 AND 1 means true. So it doesn't make any sense to explicitly use `1 AND` here.